# Remove <?php *** ?> line that contains a specific text

Tags: php, malware

A few days ago I found out I was invaded by a malicious script that has spread in all the *index.php* file , *config.php* and *wp -config.php*.

I tried to get a code and modify it to look for the files in the folders containing this script and delete it automatically.

Unfortunately I did not succeed.

The code starts like this:

```
<?php  $J24fj = 'bH1Vrb2sswS7fUn8HyCx.... AND MUCH MORE ?>
```

This code is always changing, but inside there is a constant: this text: `ZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCJaW`

I found this code, how can I change it to search for the constant and delete the entire row `<?php ******* ?>`

```
<?php 
$find='ZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCJaW';

echo findString('./',$find);

function findString($path,$find){
    $return='';
    ob_start();
    if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                if(is_dir($path.'/'.$file)){
                    $sub=findString($path.'/'.$file,$find);
                    if(isset($sub)){
                        echo $sub.PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }else{
                    $ext=substr(strtolower($file),-3);
                    if($ext=='php'){

                        $filesource=file_get_contents($path.'/'.$file);
                        //The cleaning bit
                        echo "The string '".htmlentities($find)."' was found in the file '$path/$file and has been removed from the source file.<br />";
                        $clean_source = preg_replace('#'.$find.'#','',$filesource);
                        // $clean_source = str_replace($find,'',$filesource);
                        file_put_contents($path.'/'.$file,$clean_source);
                    }else{
                        continue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
    $return = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $return;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Antonio

Comment: So you found something _malicious_ in your code. And instead of finding ways to protect your files, you instead want to keep deleting it?

Comment: First of all, you should find out how your files got infected, because maybe if you remove those lines, the files will get re-infected again. Second, You might want to just back your database up, and do a clean install of wordpress, it will be faster, and likely cleaner, reducing the risk ( even if slightly ) of still being "infected"

Comment: I'm trying to limit the damage. but in the meantime I'm trying to remove the malicious code that is found in hundreds of files scattered in the server

Comment: Hi aleation, I have 100 and more sites on my server :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well something like

preg_replace('/(\<\?php .+?)(ZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCJaWZXZhbChiYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCJaW)(.+? \?>)/'  '',$filesource);

should do the trick provided the opening and closing php tags are self-contained, i.e. do not contain any of your own code you wish to keep.

Note that preg_replace will work without copying the file's contents into a variable and then copying the new string into the $cleansource variable.

Also, you should be careful to make your changes *before* outputting a string saying that the code has been replaced!

Comment: Thank you for your response. But when I run the script will erase everything

Comment: The alternative is to such just for the string which is constant throughout all the files, then not to delete them but instead put each in an array. Then add separate tags either side to capture more and more of the offending line(s) until you have the entire string, from the opening <?php tag to the closing ?> tag. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php for examples of how to examine the preg_match_all() array.